# Libgdx : Clicklistener doesnt work on resize

Tags: android, libgdx, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

My code is fully functional if I take out screen resize concern. But now i have tried on multiple devices including tablet and the resolution is very bad. So i am trying to keep the same aspect ratio with the help of viewport. I am using stage to add my buttons and images. My clicklistener is responding to part in gutter and some part on play button. Stackoverflow is not letting me post the image because of new account. Could anyone please help me in understanding what I am doing wrong and to make sure this piece of code works on phones and desktop.

```
private static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 480;
private static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 800;

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // calculate new viewport

    Vector2 size = Scaling.fit.apply(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, width, height);
    int viewportX = (int)(width - size.x) / 2; 
    int viewportY = (int)(height - size.y) / 2;
    int viewportWidth = (int)size.x;
    int viewportHeight = (int)size.y;

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(viewportX, viewportY, viewportWidth, viewportHeight);
}

@Override
public void show() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    stage = new Stage();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);

    camera.setToOrtho(true, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);

    worldCoords  = new Vector3( VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, 0);
    camera.unproject(worldCoords);
    camera.update();


    white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"), true);
    white.setScale(1f, -1f);

    skin = new Skin();
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("button.pack.pack");
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
    buttonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button");
    buttonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("buttonpressed");
    buttonStyle.font = white;
    buttonStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;




    buttonPlay =new TextButton("Play", buttonStyle);
    buttonPlay.setWidth(VIRTUAL_WIDTH/3);
    buttonPlay.setHeight(VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/12);

    buttonPlay.setPosition(stage.getViewport().getRightGutterWidth(), stage.getViewport().getWorldHeight()/2);


    buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){

            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainFlow(g));

        }
    });

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


    Image img = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Optimized-BG_2.png")));
    img.setFillParent(true);


    stage.addActor(img);
    stage.addActor(buttonPlay);


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

}
```

Comment: the Viewport class does everything that you want.. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand exactly what do you want, but at first try to update stage, in your resize method, and read libgdx [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)

```
  stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
```